# How to add animation to HTML/CSS box, when website loads box will load with animation?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website using online Wix templates but the specific template didn't have all the things I needed so then I had to learn a little HTML/CSS. (I'm pretty new to it)

I've written the code below which shows a list of text (Company names) by sliding upwards. Once the user hovers the mouse on the text, the slider stops (onmouseover) and when the user moves the mouse pointer away from it the slider goes back to the same motion (onmouseout).

Link to some code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/WAJX9nrE

Okay so my questions are:

1. How can I animate this code so that when the webpage first loads this box will load in with some sort of animation?
2. And also instead of Company names, how can I add hyperlinks to the dedicated company's website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, add an animation for the element on page load through CSS. In the following example, this animation is called `move-up` which will run for 1 second. Additionally, to make a marquee, add an additional animation that loops. This is called `slide` in the following snippet which repeats every 16 seconds. The HTML of the companies will need to be duplicated to provide seamless looping. Finally, use a transition and the CSS `:hover` property to pause the animations when the mouse is over the card container. Here is a demo.

```css
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #888888;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* Adds animation that runs on load */
  animation-name: move-up;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  /* Adds transition */
  transition: 0.3s;
  /* Safari versions 8 and older */
  -webkit-animation-name: move-up;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}


/* Styles the container the card is in */

.card-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: show;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 16s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  
  /* More Safari compatibility... */
  -webkit-animation-name: slide;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 16s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  
}


/* Plays transition on hover */

.card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.card-container:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}


/* Defines animation on load */

@keyframes move-up {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}


/* Sliding animation */

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-1320px);
  }
}


/* Safari versions 8 and older */

@-webkit-keyframes move-up {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@-webkit-@keyframes slide {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-1320px);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card"><a href="https://example.com">Company 1</a></div>
    <div class="card"><a href="https://example.com">Company 2</a></div>
    <div class="card"><a href="https://example.com">Company 3</a></div>
    <div class="card"><a href="https://example.com">Company 4</a></div>
    <div class="card"><a href="https://example.com">Company 5</a></div>
    
    <!-- Duplicate cards are neccecary so that there is seemless looping. You may need even more if the cards do not fill the entire width of the page. -->
    <div class="card"><a href="https://example.com">Company 1</a></div>
    <div class="card"><a href="https://example.com">Company 2</a></div>
    <div class="card"><a href="https://example.com">Company 3</a></div>
    <div class="card"><a href="https://example.com">Company 4</a></div>
    <div class="card"><a href="https://example.com">Company 5</a></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed and helps a lot to get the idea for the website. &#x1F44D

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is not working please repair the link.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! This link should work: https://www.codepile.net/pile/WAJX9nrE